# Passing a URL in a XML file for XSLTransformation in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

My XSL file contains a line like this.

Click `<a href="<xsl:value-of select=""/ROOT/QUERYSTRING""/>"> here </a>` to continue...

The value "/ROOT/QUERYSTRING" is populated from a XML which would be any arbitrary URL.

But when I run the transformation, it's throwing an XSLT Compile Error at the line, `href = "<xsl`
stating,
"< is unexpected char."

Am I missing any escape chars or something?

Answer (score 1):

Rather:

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="href">
    <xsl:value-of select=""/ROOT/QUERYSTRING""/>
  </xsl:attribute>here
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... got the ans
 works!

Thanks to
http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum26/71.htm

Comment: To expand on the above a bit, the answer is to use curly brackets {} specifically: <a href="{/ROOT/QUERYSTRING}"> here </a>, I have, generally, used a variable which would give one something like: <a href="{$url}"> here </a>

Answer (score 0):

Yah, you need to use & g t; and & lt ; (added spaces otherwise the post parsed it :)